# How to blurr Grid Background Without Image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose in UserControl we have Two nested Grid layout, and I need to blur the Grid2 BackGround So the TextBlock value which is in Grid1 BackGround become Blurry. Is there any Solution or Suggestion for this how we can do without Image

```
<UserControl>
     <Grid x:name"Grid1">
          <Grid.BackGround>
              <Textblock></TextBlock>
          </Grid.backGround>
          <Grid x:Name: "Grid2">
          </Grid>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Label/TextBlock readable on glass using blur effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972476/make-label-textblock-readable-on-glass-using-blur-effect)

Comment: Here, I not want to apply blur effect in background which Contain Textblock, I need to apply blur effect on Grid2 which is empty and what ever control I keep in grid2 will not become blur.